# creating multiple grid on single chart using ECharts4R

Tags: r, echarts

I am trying to create a chart with four small charts combined, like the one demonstrated in the following link:

https://www.echartsjs.com/examples/en/editor.html?c=scatter-anscombe-quartet

The following is the script trying to create the chart:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:20, 
  testing123 = runif(20, 10, 100),
  v = runif(20, 15, 100),
  w = runif(20, 1, 100),
  z = runif(20, 25, 75)
)
df %>% 
  e_charts(x) %>% 
  e_y_axis(gridIndex = 0, min=0,max=100) %>% 
  e_y_axis(gridIndex = 1, min=0,max=100) %>% 
  e_y_axis(gridIndex = 2, min=0,max=100) %>%
  e_y_axis(gridIndex = 3, min=0,max=100) %>% 
  e_x_axis(gridIndex = 0, min=0,max=20) %>%
  e_x_axis(gridIndex = 1, min=0,max=20) %>%
  e_x_axis(gridIndex = 2, min=0,max=20) %>%
  e_x_axis(gridIndex = 3, min=0,max=20) %>% 
  e_grid(x= '7%',y='7%',width='38%',height='38%') %>%
  e_grid(x2= '7%',y='7%',width='38%',height='38%') %>%
  e_grid(x= '7%',y2='7%',width='38%',height='38%') %>%
  e_grid(x2= '7%',y2='7%',width='38%',height='38%') %>%
  e_line(serie = w, x_index = 0, y_index = 0) %>%
  e_line(serie = z, x_index = 1, y_index = 1) %>%
  e_line(serie = v, x_index = 2, y_index = 2) %>%
  e_line(serie = testing123, x_index = 3, y_index = 3) %>%
  e_tooltip(trigger = "axis")
```

But the output is not as expected:

[image]

Three lines "squeezed" into a single pane, which I expect only one line is present in each pane.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could technically replicate this with echarts4r but it's not exactly advised as the code would be extremely messy.

There is a much more convenient way than fiddling with `e_grid`. Below is an example, note that I use the same `name` so that it connects both the tooltip and the legend.

```r
library(echarts4r)

df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:20, 
  testing123 = runif(20, 10, 100),
  v = runif(20, 15, 100),
  w = runif(20, 1, 100),
  z = runif(20, 25, 75)
)

# remember to specify the ids
p1 <- e_charts(df, x, elementId = "chart1") %>% 
  e_line(serie = w, name = "common") %>% 
  e_tooltip(trigger = "axis")

p2 <- e_charts(df, x, elementId = "chart2") %>% 
  e_line(serie = v, name = "common") %>% 
  e_tooltip(trigger = "axis")

p3 <- e_charts(df, x, elementId = "chart3") %>% 
  e_line(serie = z, name = "common") %>% 
  e_tooltip(trigger = "axis")

p4 <- e_charts(df, x) %>% 
  e_line(serie = testing123, name = "common") %>% 
  e_tooltip(trigger = "axis") %>% 
  e_connect(c("chart1", "chart2", "chart3")) # connect the last chart to all others

# this is a convenience function to display the charts in a grid
e_arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, rows = 2, cols = 2)
```

It's explained further on the [website](https://echarts4r.john-coene.com/articles/connect.html)

Comment: Is there any way to adjust the spacing between the charts? I'd like to eliminate the vertical spacing in a single column arrangement in order to make it appear to be a single chart (I need y-axis breaks due to the drastically different scales in my data)